# XSL and XPATH issue match

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cd.xsl"?>
    <produce>
        <item>apple<x>kk</x><y>jj</y></item>
        <item>banana<x>aaa</x></item>
        <item>pepper<x>qqq</x></item>
    </produce>
```

and this XLS file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
    <body>
    <ul>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't understand the difference between "/" and "/*" match and for this reason I'm doing various tests, for example like those above I get this:

```
type="text/xsl" href="cd.xsl"
```

and I don't understand why.(I expected `produce` tag).

however if I use this XLS file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    version="1.0">
      <xsl:output method="html"/>

      <xsl:template match="/*">
         <html>
        <body>
        <ul>
        <li><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></li>
        </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
      </xsl:template>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get empty page(only the black point of the tag `li`).
Can you explain me those difference?

Comment: If you want to understand what an XSL transformation does, use a tool that will show you the actual resulting code (e.g. http://xsltransform.net/) - not a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you want to understand what an XSL transformation does, use a tool that will show you the actual resulting code (e.g. xsltransform.net) - not a browser. – michael.hor257k

I very much agree with this, use e.g. http://xsltransform.net/.

---

**TL;DR: `/` is the document node, `/*` is the outermost element of your input document**

The output you get from the first stylesheet is

```
<html>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>type="text/xsl" href="cd.xsl"</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

and I can see why that is surprising to you. Let's look at the XSLT code, where you match the document node:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

In this template, the only reference you are making to the input document is

```
<xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
```

which selects the value of the first node that is a child of the document node (`/`). Actually, `node()` is a set of nodes, but in XSLT 1.0, in contexts like these only the first item in such a set is used.

So, what is a node? In an XML document model (e.g. XDM) there are many different types of nodes, among others: element nodes, attribute nodes, processing instructions. Now have a look at your input document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cd.xsl"?>
<produce>
    <item>apple<x>kk</x><y>jj</y></item>
    <item>banana<x>aaa</x></item>
    <item>pepper<x>qqq</x></item>
</produce>
```

The first line is an XML declaration that is not part of the document. The second line is a processing instruction that tells your browser where to look for the XSLT stylesheet. A processing instruction *is* part of the document.

This processing instruction is the first child of the document node - which is why you get its content as the result of

```
<xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
```

---

From all this it follows that if you **remove** the processing instruction from the input document, the output will look like

```
<html>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>
            applekkjj
                    bananaaaa
                    pepperqqq

         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

because now, the `produce` element is the first child node of `/`. What you see as the result is the *string value* of the `produce` element.

---

On the other hand, if the template matches `/*`, then the output is *not* an empty page, it is

```
<html>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>

         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

`/*` means the outermost element of your XML document, in this case `produce`. Now, the `produce` element is the *context* for the `xsl:value-of`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
```

Again, this will select the first child node of the `produce` element - which is a **text node** that only contains whitespace.

Comment: ok , but I don't understand why in the last example you say that the first child of the produce element is a whitespace. why it is not the first item element?

Comment: @ginogino Because this bit: `xsl:value-of select="node()"` means: "pick the first child node of the context item, no matter what kind of node it is". Text (e.g. the whitespace-only text I was referring to) and elements **both** are nodes. `node()` is so general that it selects both text nodes and elements nodes - in this case, whatever comes first. `*` selects only elements.

Comment: Right, and while experimenting, keep in mind that `xsl:value-of` produces, as Mathia mentioned earlier, the ***string value*** of the selected node; contrast this with `xsl:copy-of`, which produces ***a copy of*** the selected node.